# By changing useState hook component is not re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, react-props

I had read many articles, in which written react re-render if shallow copy is become changed.

But in my case I'm providing a new array ,even then the component is not changing,Please tell me where I'm lagging

in following useEffect hook i'm adding **nodisplay:true**  in one of objects in videoData's (useStateHook).  to setvideoData i'm providing a new array. So it should be re-rendered the component.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (stoppedUser.length > 0)
        {
            const arr = videoData.map((e) => {
                if (stoppedUser.includes(e.id)) {
                    return { id: e.id, stream: e.stream, nodisplay: true, muted: false }
                }
                else
                    return e
            })
            setVideoData(arr)
        }
    }, [stoppedUser])
```

I want changes, in following JSX,

```
{(videoData.map((e) => (
                        <VideoComponent key={e.id} id={e.id} stream={e.stream} muted={e.muted} nodisplay={e.nodisplay} classStyle="video-container" />
                    )))}
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, can you remove some code so the question is concise and easily reproducible? There are a lot of unecessary details for the purpose of the question and I think you'll get better results.

Comment: Please see, now it seems good?

Comment: How can someone reproduce this? For example, `setVideoData` is not defined. Without being able to reproduce your results, it can result in "it works for me" responses.

Comment: Hello, Sunil, are you sure that the useEffect function is triggering?

Comment: yes,i tested triggering of useEffect with consoleLog and alert , they are functioning

Answer (score 1):

Don't put unnecessary conditions. If the videoData length is 0 it will not loop anyway.

So, Please return just ;

```js
{
  videoData.map((e) => (
    <VideoComponent key={e.id} id={e.id} stream={e.stream} muted={e.muted} nodisplay={e.nodisplay}           classStyle="video-container" />
  ))
}
```

Comment: I removed that, but the component is not re-rendering

Comment: i also removed the same part from question also.